# Elements in array from Json Api

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, xcode, api

I want to collect all value's from "price" into array, and count, but sadly all time i got 0 items in array. please be lenient im new into obj-c.

```
        NSData *data = [apiHandler getResponseFromPublicServerUrl:@"https://bitcoinity.org/markets/get_depth_change?currency=USD&exchange=btce&dc_span=10m"];

        NSError* error;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];

        NSArray *resultArray = [json objectForKey:@"price"];

        NSLog (@"Number of elements in array = %lu", [resultArray count]);
```

Comment: `NSDictionary* json` should be `NSArray* json`... JSON return arrays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following code snippet.

```
NSError* error;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];


    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[json valueForKey:@"data"] mutableArrayValueForKeyPath:@"price"];
    NSLog (@"Number of element count = %d and Number of elements of array = %@", [resultArray count],  resultArray);

mutableArrayValueForKeyPath method give you all values under key of price.
```